# Transport scheme NOT recognized: [tcp]

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

It has been years since I worked with activeMQ some. I am now implementing a new activeMQ server with client apps on the inside and outside.

I tested my outside client app locally, but when I deployed it, I started getting errors like:

```
2014-04-10 08:01:31,392 [signInResultListenerContainer-1] ERROR org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue://signInResult' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [tcp]
```

I checked the firewall on my server and it is wide open.

```
<bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://xxx.30.8.163:61616"/>
</bean>
```

Any ideas on what is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you don't have the necessary resources in your classpath. Take a look at this [similar issue](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/JMSException-transport-scheme-NOT-recognised-occurs-when-project-is-jarred-up-td2383618.html) and check the ActiveMQ jars/resources from the classpath.

Comment: I am bringing in activemq-all jar file. This is a stand-alone jar, so I'm simply bringing all of the classes over. Do you have any idea what class name I might be missing?

Comment: OIC, META-INF/services stuff. I simply copied everything under META-INF into my jar and it appears to be working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not about a class, but a file under activemq-all.jar\META-INF\services\org\apache\activemq\transport\tcp which defines the tcp transport implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to resolve is to prefill the ConnectionFactory with connections by setting the prefill element to true in the ra config

```
        <connection-definitions>
            <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">
                <xa-pool>
                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                </xa-pool>
            </connection-definition>
        </connection-definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spring Boot, and this is what solved it for me:

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
> ```