# ActiveMQ Java consumer throws Transport scheme NOT recognized: [tcp]

Tags: java, ant, jms, activemq-classic

I have created the ActiveMQ consumer file in Java. When I am trying to connect to ActiveMQ it shows:

```
exception in run method::javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [tcp]
```

When I run the same consumer file as a standalone file its working properly, but with Ant build its not working. I have included activemq-all.jar in build path. But still its not working.

Connection URL: `tcp://localhost:61616`

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.ExceptionListener;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

    private void createConnection(String USER, String PASSWORD, String connectionURL) throws Exception{
        this.connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(USER, PASSWORD, connectionURL);
         // connectionURL = tcp://localhost:61616
        // Create a Connection
        this.connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        connection.setExceptionListener(this);
        // Create a Session
        this.session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }
```

Comment: You can look into the Solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987656/transport-scheme-not-recognized-tcp

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to ANT build.
I have removed the META-INF while creating destination jar
`<zipfileset src="activemq-all.jar" excludes="META-INF/**" />`

then i have replaced it with the below mentioned command alone:
`<zipfileset src="activemq-all.jar">`